# Cannot connect to WMI provider, SQL Server Configuration manager

Tags: sql-server

I cant connect to SQL Server Configuration manager. 
I have installed SQL Server 2014 x64 Standard edition and [SQL Server Management Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx) ,which I can open and work with. Just to point out, that I am doing clean installation of windows, so there is no other SQL instances on this computer.

But I cant run SQL server Configuration manager here is the full error
[image]

So, there is an a[rticle on Microsoft web site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/956013) that says way issue is present and gives an workaround.

Basicly it says

> This problem occurs because the WMI provider is removed when you
>   uninstall an instance of SQL Server. The 32-bit instance and the
>   64-bit instance of SQL Server share the same WMI configuration file.
>   This file is located in the %programfiles(x86)% folder.

But there is no other SQL instance, and I haven't removed anything. But when I go to %programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\ there are files and folders present. So, my guess was OK It installs something for 32-bit. Stupid of me, but I have run the command in CMD.exe

> C:\Windows\system32>mofcomp "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\120\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof" Microsoft (R) MOF
>   Compiler Version 10.0.10586.0 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corp. 1997-2006.
>   All rights reserved. Parsing MOF file: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof MOF
>   file has been successfully parsed Storing data in the repository...
>   Done!

Needles to say, the same issue Cannot connect to WMI provider.. is still present.

Comment: I suspect this might be caused due to WMI corruption,Can you try repairing WMI..http://superuser.com/questions/190960/repair-wmi-on-windows-7